# Get Post Full Path in Jekyll/Octopress

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, octopress

In Octopress, I'm trying to get a post's full file path (something like `~/projects/site/source/_posts/2012-01-01-something.markdown`) by extending the `Jekyll:Post` class.

```
module Jekyll
    class Post
        alias_method :original_to_liquid, :to_liquid
        def to_liquid
            # test if this function is actually called
            puts "hello"
            original_to_liquid.deep_merge({
                'full_path' => File.join(@base,@name)
            })
        end
    end
 end
```

I name this file as `full_path.rb` and put it in the `plugins` folder. Oddly, my `to_liquid` function never get called, since the `hello` message didn't show up.

Even more strange, I find the `date.rb` shipped with Octopress also defines `to_liquid` method of `class Post`, so I add the `full_path => File.join(@base,@name)` line there and it works! I'm soooo confused.

So my question is, why my `to_liquid` method didn't get called?

## UPDATE

After upgrading jekyll from 0.12.0 to 1.2.1, it magically works......

Comment: What you're looking for is already there in Question [How to Get the Full Path of Markdown Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406314/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-full-path-of-the-markdown-post-in-jekyll?s=2|1.2782)

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at the `Post#permalink` [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mojombo/jekyll/master/Jekyll/Post#permalink-instance_method). It should do what you want without having to create new plugins.

(if I misunderstood you, maybe [containing_dir](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mojombo/jekyll/master/Jekyll/Post#containing_dir-instance_method) is the method you're looking for)

Comment: `permalink`(e.g.,`/2012/01/01/something/index.html`) is not what I want. I need to the the post file's full path in Linux. Also, for `containing_dir`, I don't have `source` and `dir` to pass in.
It'll be perfect if I can access Post's `@base` and `@name`, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: The thing is, I'm writing a Liquid `Tag` that show the git history of the post file. In `render`, I can only get the liquid hash of post, so I want to merge the full path in post's data hash.

Comment: What bothers me most is that, my own `to_liquid` method has no effect at all. I just don't get it why....

Comment: Well, you were using an "ancient" version of Jekyll and there have been lots of effort to improve it since them. Always upgrade your libraries! :P

Comment: Year, the thing is, I'm using Octopress, which's kind of outdated a little bit.... I'm considering switching back to pure Jekyll.