# Is there a way to get the full path of the markdown post in jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I created a blog just for my personal use. Just to organize my own notes.

Unlike a proper blog where after you write the post you are usually done. I will be editing these post frequently, so in the footer I want to have the following:

```
sublime /path/to/_posts/markdown-post.md
```

So that I copy it and paste it in my terminal.

So is there a way to get all that information dynamically. Or at least the full markdown file name (I could hard code the path myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{ site.source }}` will give you absolute path to your site root.

`{{ page.path }}` will give you page path relative to site root.

Finally `subl {{ site.source }}/{{ page.path }}` will do the trick.